# Can ETL access Data while Rebuild Index Operation is running

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, etl

Can I get some help to understand below questions:

We have a ETL job running (Datawarehouse Server) and weekly index operations (Production Server)(Ola Hallengren script) , below questions are scenario based .

NOTE: For Index optimization we are using the Ola Hallengren script.

1. If a ETL Job and Rebuild Index Job (Ola Hallengren script) scheduled at same time what are the high disadvantages.
2. How do I know in a simple way whether my Index Rebuild operation (Ola Hallengren script) is Offline or Online ?
3. What are the Lock types occur while Rebuild Ops in execution ?
4. Will Blocking or Deadlocks occur if a transaction is trying to access while the DB is in Rebuild Index Operation (Ola Hallengren script).

Regards

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server?  Enterprise or Stanard? (SELECT @@VERSION)

Comment: Why do you need to rebuild indexes?

Comment: Hi @sp_BlitzErik , I updated my question. We are using the Ola Hallengren code for Index Optimization. I set this as a weekly task for SQL Server performance maintenance .

Answer (score 0):

> If a ETL Job and Rebuild Index Job (Ola Hallengren script) scheduled at same time what are the high disadvantages.

You would be having all sorts of blocking or even deadlocks depending on what the ETL process is doing. Please note index rebuild reorganize and stats updte are "maintenance" operations and should be best done during application downtime o when load is relatively very less.
Index rebuild/reorganize should only be done *if* the index is fraganted. Accepted value for rebuild is when `fragmentation > 30 %` and for reorganize is when `fragmentation is between 10 and 20 %`. Plus there is NO NEED to do any kind of index operation on small indexes having `page_count < 2000`.

> How do I know in a simple way whether my Index Rebuild operation (Ola Hallengren script) is Offline or Online ?.

Just see the Ola's script you are running in SQL Server agent or manually, you have option to specify both online and offline rebuild below is a dummy script.

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',---both offline and online index rebuild can be done, priority taken from left.
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

read below description for what the various parameters means.

[image]

**Additional information:**

Online index rebuild if enterprise only feature but there are chances you might not be using it. Other way to find out is to see the script you are running or maintenance plan. If you are using MP you would see option like "Keep Index Online" as shown below

[image]

This is from SSMS 2016 the option might be same but used somewhere else in other SSMS versions.

if you are using TSQL

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Production.Product  
REBUILD WITH   
(  
    FILLFACTOR = 80,   
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,  
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON,  
    ONLINE = ON ,  ----see this index rebuild is using ONLINE=ON
    DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW  
);
```

> What are the Lock types occur while Rebuild Ops in execution ?

For online index rebuild Online it take two very short-term table locks. An S (Shared) table lock at the start of the operation to force all write plans that could touch the index to recompile, and a SCH-M (Schema-Modification – think of it as an Exclusive) table lock at the end of operation to force all read and write plans that could touch the index to recompile. There may be other locks but I do not have whole list you can fire up the command on test instance and see the locks using DMV [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For offline index operation it takes Schema modification locks, exclusive locks and intent exclusive locks and many others. You can refer to [Logging in Online and Offline Index Rebuild](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24420.sql-server-curious-case-of-logging-in-online-and-offline-index-rebuild-in-full-recovery-model.aspx#Performing_The_Test) and get complete information by running DMV sys.dm_tran_locks.

> Will Blocking or Deadlocks occur if a transaction is trying to access while the DB is in Rebuild Index Operation (Ola Hallengren script).

Yes quite likely and this can happen both in offline and online index rebuild.

Comment: Shanky, He is not using MP, he's using Ola Hallengren script. @DBOn, look at yor parameters FragmentationLow/FragmentationMedium/FragmentationHigh, there is a specification if you want to rebuild online or offline

Comment: Yep corrected it, I added the snippet from Ola's script.